# how do i create this type of element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following `HTML`:

```
<fb:like show_faces="false" action='like'/>
```

How do I convert this to JavaScript (no jQuery) **Specifically, create an element like so..**

I hope this question does not get marked as closed I dont really know what to do so I dont have any more code samples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var test = document.createElement("fb:like");
test.setAttribute("show_faces", "false");
test.setAttribute("action", "like");
```